# AWS Restoring MySQL instances on a daily schedule programmatically with snapshots

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been hunting for a way within the AWS facilities to perform a daily restore of an RDS snapshot using something like a cron job for a demo development application. This way everyday, the database will look the same for people demoing their product, but the "demoers" will be able to change data inside the DB; it cannot be read-only.

We are able to do this manually, have looked at the lambda functions (which seem to time-out) and scoured the blogs/forums/doc.  Surely, this would be a necessary feature for someone? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: While doing the demo is the user planning to add some changes that will add changes to the database too?

Comment: Exactly, this is the idea and there will be data being added live throughout the day with graphs being changed etc...

Comment: Restoring from a snapshot creates a new RDS instance.  You don't have to wait for that to complete, so it's not clear what you mean about a timeout.  Start the restore at, say, 8PM, and then at, say, 4AM, rename the outgoing instance, rename the incoming instance, and destroy the outgoing instance, using Lambda functions and scheduled events to fire them off.

Comment: Do you have the code for a lambda function which performs this?